# Database Default Locations doesn't persist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I set the default location for the Data & Log in the Server Properties in SQL Server 2012, and click Ok, it resets back to the previous value immediately - if I reopen the Server Properties, the values has been reset.

How do I get it to persist? I'm trying to set it to a location on a separate HDD. The Backup folder location has been changed without issue.

Comment: Please have a look at answer given by Sethu Srinivasan in this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5704312c-bf9c-4908-ad90-f4d8bbcb26a9/how-to-change-the-default-backup-location

Comment: Same result - doesn't persist. I suspect it's because the account doesn't have permission to that drive. Need to find how which account it is and try give it access.

Comment: Hmm. Nope. Granted MSSQLSERVER access to the disk, so I could at least find the backups on the disk, but the default location changes still don't persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure the account running the SQLservice should have the required rights on the directory you are wishing to change:

2) Also, you can give a try with below T-SQL

You can also do the same with T-SQL and here is the T-SQL code to do the same.

/* I am trying to change to D drive in below example*/

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', REG_SZ, N'D:\DATA'
GO
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', REG_SZ, N'D:\DATA'
GO
```

3. Most important:-**After Changing the Default Locations**

*You must stop and start the SQL Server service to complete the change*

Comment: @Kapil This is not supported way to do, please see link posted by me in my first comment. You an see MS employee saying this is not supported way.

Comment: I don't even have those keys in the registry....

Comment: @Shanky, we did and worked but noted of that being not supported. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @SeanW: after changing default locations did you restarted the services.

Comment: Got it - needed to do a reboot. I had tried stopping & restarting the service via Services, but that didn't seem to work. I didn't change the settings in the registry, though - just used the normal SSMS setting and then rebooted.

Comment: Marking yours as the answer as your comment prompted me to reboot, although I would prefer not to use the registry.

Comment: @SeanW If you change the paths in the UI and then click the "Script" button, you'll see that the UI accomplishes this by writing to the registry. The trick is you need to make sure you're writing to the right location.